# Issue with GeckoFX Web Browser 33

Tags: c#, winforms, geckofx

I have a WinFrom project in VS 2013 which I embedded GeckoFX webbrowser control to display web page inside the form. The GeckoFX Web Browser and XULRunner I am using is 33.0.

When I call GeckoWebBrowser.Navigavte(url), it works fine and displays the web page I am requesting. However, when I call geckoWebBrowser1.Refresh(), the WebBrowser control does not refresh the page. I also tested GoBack and GoForward functions, it all works fine.

Can anyone help me with this refresh issue?

Thanks

Jing

Comment: Try `geckoWebBrowser1.Reload();`. Or you can also use `geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate(geckoWebBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri);`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a WinForm project in VS 2014 with GeckoFX. @IT Captain's solution is the correct answer. When I use Reload() it works while Refresh() doesn't.